# bash store output as a variable

Tags: linux, bash

```
grep -A 26 "some text" somefile.txt |
   awk '/other text/ { gsub(/M/, " "); print $4 }' |
   sort -n -r | uniq | head -1
```

will return the largest in a list pulled from a large text file, but how do I store the output as a variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

```
my_var=$(grep -A 26 "some text" somefile.txt |
   awk '/other text/ { gsub(/M/, " "); print $4 }' |
   sort -n -r | uniq | head -n1)
```

Also, for portability, I would suggest always using `-n1` for the argument of `head`. I've come across a couple of incarnations of it where using `-1` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For unnested cases back quotes will work too:

```
variable=`grep -A 26 "some text" somefile.txt |   
awk '/other text/ { gsub(/M/, " "); print $4 }' |  
sort -nru | head -1`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest

```
variable_name=$(grep -A 26 "some text" somefile.txt |
     awk '/other text/ { gsub(/M/, " "); print $4 }' |
     sort -nru | head -1)
```