# Bash script to get variable from second bash script

Tags: linux, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bash store output as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704740/bash-store-output-as-a-variable)

I have a script that outputs a simple integer like "10", then i have a second script where i want to call this script and grab the integer as a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

KBPS= ## NEED OUTPUT FROM /USR/LOCAL/BIN/ETH0TX.SH
THRESHOLD=50 #KBPS
if [ $KBPS -gt $THRESHOLD ]; then
   exit 1
fi
```

Is that possible?

Comment: i tried various combinations some very similar to the solution. do i need to list everything that didn't work?

Comment: Yes, mostly if already purposed answer did'nt make your job!

Comment: i think its perfectly acceptable to ask a simple question, get a simple answer without posting inaccurate code. But in a lot of cases i agree you should show your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
KBPS=$(/usr/local/bin/eth0tx.sh)
```

Comment: thanks everyone! first answer wins

Answer (score 0):

```
KBPS=$(/usr/local/bin/eth0tx.sh)
```

will set `KBPS` to the output of your script. Capitalisation removed. You can check the exit code with `$?`. That may be worth doing rather than simply populate `KBPS` with invalid/blank data.

More info [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html), and note the comments re. whitespace/newlines etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is:

```
KBPS=$(theotherbashscript)
```

This is called command substitution.

Note: requires that the output does not contain spaces.

Comment: If you're worried about spaces, you can quote the string that you're capturing via command substitution: `KBPS="$(theotherbashscript)"`.

Answer (score 0):

`KBPS=$(/usr/local/bin/eth0tx.sh)`

What a race! :D